# Message Template placeholders on AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, email

I'm trying to configure AWS Cognito to send a verification email containing a custom one-click link. Following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-message-templates.html) I created this link into my template:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/verify/{username}/{####}">Click on the link</a>
```

Since `{username}` is a valid template token, I expected it to be changed into the actual username when a verification email is sent, but it's not.
I also tried a couple of advanced tokens, like `{ip-address}` and `{country}`, without success. What am I missing here?

Edit: I'm trying this on eu-central-1, verification type is `code` and here's a screenshot from the AWS Console:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all given [message template placeholders](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-message-templates.html) work for all custom message workflows. For instance, email verification I couldn't make any placeholder work but verification code {####}. It is not mentioned in AWS documentation though but that's my experience.

I managed to achieve it using [Lambda custom message triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html). Much easier to implement and provide a lot more customisation options.

Comment: Yes, I will give it a try. It's somehow irritating that it's wrongly documented, but at least I know that I didn't miss anything. Thanks for the feedback!